# I cannot run firebase commands in my terminal

Tags: firebase

I installed firebase using `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` command on my Mac. Then I try to run `firebase -v`, it gives the below error.

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/randiltennakoon/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json'
You don't have access to this file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was searching regarding this issue, I found this [webpage](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/864).

So, according to that, I ran `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/configstore` on my terminal & it fixed my issue. Now I can see the firebase version using the `firebase -V` command.